# Sublime Text custom syntax highlighting

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm working on a custom syntax highlighting and copied few snippets from the HTML syntax since this piece is very similar. I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to highlight the text inside of tags. Here is my definition:

```
- match: "(</?)([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)"
  captures:
    1: punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
    2: entity.name.tag.other.html
  push:
    - meta_scope: meta.tag.other.html
    - match: '>'
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      pop: true
    - match: '.'
      scope: string.quoted.single.html
```

Samle text:

```
<file bash>
Some bash code block
Some bash code block
</file>
```

My code highlights the brackets `<>`, the `file` and `bash` keywords, but I can't figure out how to add color to the block inside. Ultimately I want to have it as a block comment or something similar so it will stand out. Any suggestions?

I need a solution that avoids adding the comment highlighting for tags that have no closing tag. For example there are certain tags in the markup I'm working with that don't use closing, such as `<tag without close>` that doesn't have `</tag>`. Any way to add an exclusion in the regex to only work if there is open and close tags, but not when there is only open tag?

```
<tag without close>
This should not be a comment.

<file bash>
This should be a comment.
</file>

This also should not be a comment.
```

Only a small selection of tags will be used like `<tag>` above, mostly for metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, based loosely on how the [interiors of both `<style>` and `<script>` are managed](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax#L72-L87), is to use a `with_prototype` which has a `pop`.

```
- match: '(?:^\s+)?(<)([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)\b(?![^>]*/>)'
  captures:
    1: punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
    2: entity.name.tag.other.html
  push:
    - match: '(</)(\2)(>)'
      captures:
        1: punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
        2: entity.name.tag.other.html
        3: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      pop: true
    - match: '>'
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      push:
        - match: '.'
          scope: comment.block.html
      with_prototype:
        - match: (?=</\2)
          pop: true
        - include: main
    - match: '.'
      scope: string.quoted.single.html
```

Note that the `([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)` here is matching any valid tag name, as you were in your question, and `\2` is used to match that group later, both in the immediate decoupling `match` condition and in the `with_prototype` condition. The [`with_protoype`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) defines patterns that are applied to everything in the current context, so here we use it to make sure we `pop` the comment-esque highlighting once we reach a `</file>`, rather than being treated as part of the comment.

Within the `with_prototype`, the `- include: main` statement ensures that any tags within your comment-like content behave like the outer `<file>` tags. For example, `<hello>` below acts just the same as `<file>`.

```
<file bash>
Some bash code block
<hello stuff>
Some bash code block
</hello>
Some bash code block
</file>
```

---

If you have tags that don't have matching end tags, you can override this behaviour by defining specific behaviour for those tags higher up the stack, like so:

```
- match: '(?:^\s+)?(<)(hello)\b(?![^>]*/>)'
  captures:
    1: punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
    2: entity.name.tag.other.html
  push:
    - match: '>'
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      pop: true
    - match: '.'
      scope: string.quoted.single.html
```

Provided this is earlier than the `match: '(?:^\s+)?(<)([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)\b(?![^>]*/>)'` line, any `<hello>` tags will not invoke the comment-esque highlighting.

This text is not comment.block.html.

Some bash code block
Some bash code block
Some bash code block

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic and way more advanced than what I was looking for! Also appreciate the explanation, it helps learning. This code works great in 99% of the cases, except when there is no closing tag.

Comment: In what scenario would you want to highlight a block as if it's a comment without there being a closing tag? @user1781482

Comment: I guess the idea is to threat anything between open and close tag as a block. If there is only open tag, but no close tag, there wouldn't be any block.

Comment: Maybe this should be broken into two separate parts to avoid over complicating it. So one case would be to highlight `<some text in tags>` and the other case would be `<tag open>block quote text</tag close>`

Comment: @user1781482 I'm not sure that's possible while keeping it open to all tags, but if only certain tags are going to have the comments – say it were `file` and `rank` – you can always use something like `(file|rank)` in place of the `([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)` in that first `match`.

Comment: There are only couple of tags that don't have closing, mostly for metadata. Those can be put on the bottom of the text, so it doesn't screw up the highlighting. Your solution is great, thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125187/discussion-between-robin-james-kerrison-and-user1781482).